# Implementing Navigation drawer along Sliding tabs

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, sliding, drawer

I was trying to implement navigation drawer along with Sliding tabs!
My app is crashing!

I think there is some error with Navigation drawer Fragment or Activity_Main.xml

[Project files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B11Pf9lY_5OgfmJuLXFGMUR1QjhaYTh3NDJQUFV5WnRxaXdXTUJmOEdKendLYVVmQkpRcFU&usp=sharing)

Here is a logcat:
[Log Cat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11Pf9lY_5OgckNpWVIxSGtNVlk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Implement Navigation drawer with action bar tabs [Follow the steps](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: Can you help me implementing Navigation drawer with Navigation Drawer!